# Splash Screen on Android not working

Tags: android, splash-screen

I'm developing an Android app.
The app should show a Splash Screen at startup while checking if a file is updated. If the file is not updated, it launches an Async Task to update the file.
The problem is, the image of the Splash Screen only shows when the file actually needs updating. Else, a black screen shows while performing the check.

My SplashScreen activity:

```
    public class SplashActivity extends Activity
{
    private final static String placesFile = "places";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        if(!isFileUpdated()){
            new PlacesService(this).execute();
        }else{
            intentAndFinish();
        }

    }
    private void intentAndFinish() {
        finish();
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainIntent);  
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return false if Places Data is too old
     */
    private boolean isFileUpdated() {
        int daysOld = 0;
        File f = new File(this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() +"/"+placesFile);
        if(f.exists()){
            System.out.println("existe");
        }
        Date d = new Date();
        Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        d.setTime(f.lastModified());
        if(currentDate.compareTo(d)>0)
            daysOld = determineDifferenceInDays(d, currentDate);
        return daysOld < Consts.PLACES_DAYS_OLD_QTY_PERMITTED?true:false;
    }
    private static int determineDifferenceInDays(Date date1, Date date2) {
        Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar1.setTime(date1);
        Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar2.setTime(date2);
        long diffInMillis = calendar2.getTimeInMillis() - calendar1.getTimeInMillis();
        return (int) (diffInMillis / (24* 1000 * 60 * 60));
    }

    public void onResultFromAsyncTask(boolean finished) {
        if(finished){
            intentAndFinish();
        }
    }
}
```

activity_splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/splash_es"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i think you are closing your activity if file is activated in onResume

Comment: please create asyntask in separate class don't sync in same activity class

Comment: Remove your `XML` and post your `AsyncTask`.

Comment: How much time does the check actually take? What happends if you put finish(); after startActivity(mainintent) in our intentAndFinish()?

Comment: @DavidOlsson his computation is taking all comparisons using Date class's time which will not take longer enough visible to human eyes..In low end phones tat much time is even lesser than how much it takes to start a app

Comment: @sheetal, that test should still show the splash layout. If the check is so fast an eye can't see it he shouldn't see a black screen either, in that case the MainActivity should start directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are killing your Splash before it be on the Screen. Because you are killing it inside the onResume method. Look this piece of documentation:

> The **foreground lifetime** of an activity happens between a call to onResume() until a corresponding call to onPause(). During this time the activity is in front of all other activities and interacting with the user. An activity can frequently go between the resumed and paused states -- for example when the device goes to sleep, when an activity result is delivered, when a new intent is delivered -- so the code in these methods should be fairly lightweight.

You can use a handler, it is more elegant than Thread to solve this problem, but the main ideia is the same of @sheetal.

On onCreate method:

```
 handler = new Handler();
```

On onResume method:

```
   handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      if(!isFileUpdated()){
        new PlacesService(this).execute();
      }else{
        intentAndFinish();
      }
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you @Bruno. Not only you provided the answer but also an explanation on activities lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is updated You are closing your activity in onResume and switching to main activity and the process will take fraction of milliseconds to do that..so it is very much possible you will never see your spash screen..If you want you can use

```
  private void intentAndFinish() {
     Thread.sleep(10000)
    finish();
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(mainIntent);  
}
```

Just to catch up with your splashScreen.

See @bruno 's post...We should use a handler

Comment: Shouldn't use thread.sleep on ui thread since that will most likely cause an ANR.

Comment: @DavidOlsson ohkk but luk at his code..He will never see his SplashScreen that way..In on resume only he is switching activity..Okk than using Handler can be a good way

Comment: I don't want to make the user wait for nothing. I meant for the splash screen to show while doing something in background.

Answer (score 0):

You call to isFileUpdated() takes time put it in background
You asyntask should be something like this

```
    public class PlacesService extends Asynctask<Void,Void,Void>{
    boolean flag=false
    public Void doInBackground(){
    flag=isFileUpdated()
    if (!flag){
    return
    }else {
    // Do your file update
    }
    return 

    }

public onPostExcecute(){
intentAndFinish();

}
    }
```